# Create a RTMP server within a Xamarin forms app / Connect 360 camera to application

Tags: xamarin, camera, video-streaming, rtmp

I need to create an app where I need to connect to a 360 camera (like the Insta360) to record things and keep accessing the internet.
So I was thinking to create a hotspot with the device running the app so that the camera can connect to it and start streaming to the device so that I can get the video stream and deal with it in the app.

Is their a way to do that or another way maybe less weird and easier ?…

Thanks in advance

Comment: It feels like your problem is too broad. Can you elaborate on your problem ? What have you tried?

Comment: I manage to save every load of data as image in tmp folder of my app then encode with ffmpeg but it's realy long and cpu intensive. any idea to directly encode the websocket data to a video or is it not possible ?